# Why does the Google Analytics API method return less data than web ui

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Do the Google Analytics API methods allow to get the same amount of data, that is accessible through the web UI?

The problem is, for example, that in browser I can see more that 3000 lines in a report, but the API method returs only several hundreds.

Here is a URL for API method that I use:
https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga%3A73XXXXXX&dimensions=ga%3ApagePath%2Cga%3Akeyword&metrics=ga%3Avisits%2Cga%3AvisitBounceRate&sort=-ga%3Avisits&start-date=2015-09-01&end-date=2015-09-30&start-index=1&max-results=3000

Answer (score 0):

The API method you are using has queries appended on it. (Everything after the '?' and seperated by the '&') These are not part of the URL but actually information that is used by the server to customize your result. By changing the URL to say: https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga%3A73XXXXXX&dimensions=ga%3ApagePath%2Cga%3Akeyword&metrics=ga%3Avisits%2Cga%3AvisitBounceRate&sort=-ga%3Avisits&start-date=2015-09-01&end-date=2015-09-30&start-index=1&**max-results=10000** , you should get more results in your response. You may also want to change the start and end date, just make sure to keep the YYYY-MM-DD format.

Comment: The problem is in the fact that it returns only about 350 results in an array while the page size is set to the value 3000. And in the Web UI I can retrieve about 3500 results for the same datetime period.

Also I tried deviding the whole datetime period to the many of short ones (like 01.01-02.01, 02.01-03.01, etc.). But the amount of total results was the same.